# Are the classes repeated in Critical CSS?

Tags: css, critical-css

I'm trying to understand [Critical CSS](https://criticalcss.com/).

I understand that with Critical CSS the tools extract vital CSS that is important for content at the 'top of the fold' to load.

The bit that I struggle with is this: is the DOM and the browser expected to then load the entire CSS (placed further down the page) again? The result of this would mean that CSS classes would be repeated, which doesn't make much sense.

Said another way - is the entire CSS file divided, and therefore there are NO repeated classes?

Comment: Did you understand that you need to put CSS file twice?

Comment: So we do add the SAME CSS file twice?  Is that correct?

Comment: What is Critical CSS?

Comment: It's a way to speed up top things f the role content

Comment: This article is useful,   https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/08/understanding-critical-css/

Comment: Critical CSS itself doesn't make much sense. I mean I guess it kinda does in theory, but in practice you can't expect the fold to be the same across all media, so there's no way to determine which CSS is critical except that which is common to all media.

Comment: Learn what/how CSS does/work and you will be in control of what loads and how fast, free of charge. With that knowledge you will be able to decide whether a framework will do more than cost you money.